# Regex for multiple lines python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

> "
>
> In the Matter of
>
> XYZ-ABCD
>
> Respondent.
>
> "

Stashed away at some part of a pdf file. I am only interested in capturing the 
XYZ-ABCD part but apparently the regex I am using in python is not capturing the pattern correctly.

The piece of text I am interested in capturing can appear anywhere within the PDF and I am using the following pattern:

```
 pat = "^\n+In the Matter of\n+(\s+\w+\s*)\n+ 
 (Respondent\.|Respondents\.)\s+$"
```

This is the regex code I am using to capture

```
 str = re.match(pat,input_str)
```

Obviously, I have included the `\n` to take care of the multiple lines,
However, I don't seem to be getting any matches and don't seem to see what I am missing in my pattern that has not included. This also includes partial matches which I don't seem to be getting.

Comment: Have you tried giving the positional argument `re.MULTILINE` at the end of your regex call? For that matter, can you show us the actual regex call you're currently trying to use (that is, the code involved in this question)?

Comment: is [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/YCcT8s/3/) what you're looking for ?, your `\s+` should be `\s*` i.e `(\s*\w+\s*)`

Comment: If you are on Windows you might need `\r\n` for new lines. Can you break down your regex bit by bit until it does give a match? Then you should be able to tell us the exact regex character that is giving issues (or maybe the answer will become obvious to you).

Comment: There is no dash - in a word `\w` try `[-\w]` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^\s+In the Matter of\s+(\S+)\s+Respondents?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dIfWZb/1) (mind the multiline flag).

---

Some issues with your original expression:

```
\n != \s       # \s includes \n but also other whitespace characters
\w = [A-Z0-9_] # but you wanted to match "-" as well which is not part of \w
```

Additionally, you had likely neither the multiline nor the verbose flag on but your code snippet looked like you would have needed to.